# Resources for learning ASP.NET MVC 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

What are some good resources for learning ASP.NET MVC 2.0 (if I don't already know ASP.NET MVC 1.0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Obviously the first resource I'd point you to is the [official ASP MVC website here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/).**

Perhaps the **biggest** and **most key** aspect you need to understand about ASP.NET MVC is that MVC **isn't** explicitly specialised for ASP.NET - it's a **very wide [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science))** - MVC stands for [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you should really read up on MVC and gain a general understanding **before** you dive straight into the ASP.NET implementation.

You may want to look into **buying a book** that can nicely ease you into ASP.NET MVC. The reviews on amazon are something you want to take into account, as they're usually very accurate.

**You can find results of a [ASP.NET MVC search here](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=search+ASP.NET+MVC&x=0&y=0).**

---

As far as your concerns around version 1 to version 2 of ASP.NET MVC go, you **shouldn't** automatically dismiss any ASP.NET MVC v1 resources you come across - the chances are it's **still relevant**. You may wish to check out the **changelist** between v1 and v2 to see if anything you learn is now **redundant, updated or changed** in any way.

Answer (score 3):

Tekpub (Steven Sanderson and Rob Conery) is doing a video series on MVC 2: http://tekpub.com/preview/aspmvc

Comment: they charge people ridiculous amounts $20 for a 9 minute episode

Comment: That is a preview vid only. It's $25 or so I think and it's for a whole series (if you don't have a subscription); there will something like 8 episodes I would think and each episode of the one's I bought so far are around 30-40 mins long. Ask Rob Conery for details on Twitter or via the site.

Comment: they only have 3 episodes or so now... would you like to go halvies in your bill and share?

Comment: $28 = less than a Wrox book. It's a professional learning tool, not the latest Miley Cyrus CD.

Comment: im just not sure if they will come out with the "8" espisodes in time, if they are released 6 months later then there really is no point to any of it!!

Comment: I work with Rob on TekPub and just wanted to clarify that it is $28 for all the episodes (8-10) and they will cover ASP.NET MVC 2.0 in depth. All of the episodes will be released before 6 months I am sure, and most likely well before any book on the subject. 

Also the license you buy is for one user, please don't share or you are just hurting the authors who spend their time recording these.

Comment: if you could give us a timeline that would be great, the money is really no issue... if i can guarantee some comprehensive mvc 2.0 documentation or coverage (without having to sort through 1.0 material) then i would almost consider moving my webforms project to mvc... but for this i'd really need to knwo when the 8th or 10th eps will be out!... any ideas?

Comment: there is only two episodes at the moment!!! there is just not enough material to move forward with!!

Answer (score 1):

There is going to be a lot of help around for MVC 1.  If you're looking to learn .NET MVC then most of .NET MVC 1 is relevant.  Phil Haack is one of many who has blogged about the [blogged about the release of .NET MVC 2](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/17/aspnetmvc-2-rc.aspx). Importantly, he gives a link to the [release notes](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=157072).

Not a great deal has actually changed. Mainly to do with validation in fact.  You can use the release notes as a guide. Whenever you're doing something that is 'flagged' in the release notes, then make sure you look for .NET MVC2 help specifically.

Comment: I highly recommend the release notes.

Answer (score 1):

Brad Wilson has some [nice posts about templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html).